# Why am I getting "Class 'App\Models\NewMod' not found" error?

Tags: laravel-5

I am getting `App/Models error` every time . I have tried the previous solutions given for this problem but none of them could help me. I have changed the name of the model and controller for several times to check whether it is a naming convention problem but could not solve it.

in model:

```
namespace App\models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class NewMod extends Model
{
 public function add()
{DB::connection('lara1')->insert("insert into abc (id, name) values (?, 
?)', [2, 'pqr']);")}
}
}
```

in controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\NewMod ;

class NewModController extends Controller
{
public function add()
{
    /*$a= $_GET["name"];

    DB::insert('insert into abc (id, name) values (?, ?)', [2, $a]);*/
    $l= new NewMod();
    $l->add;
    echo "record inserted ";
}
}
```

in route:

```
Route::get('ax', 'NewModController@add');
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
use App\Models\NewMod ;
```

with

```
use App\models\NewMod ;
```

if your folder name is Models

replace

```
namespace App\models;
```

with

```
namespace App\Models;
```

Comment: still I get this "Class 'App\models\NewMod' not found"

Comment: what is your folder name  models or Models? change accordingly in namespace too

Comment: I did not create any folder named Model or model . Now I have solved the problem by creating a folder named Model. Thanks for your answer

Comment: please select the answer if it help you and can be helpful for others!